# Query/formula in Excel to select min/max values for a category/group and assign a new description

Tags: excel, group-by, max, assign, minimum

Since I don't have a lot experience creating a query/formula in Excel, I'm hoping some expert can help me with syntax.

I would like a query or formula that can look at a variable in one column that has the same name (a group) and select the min. and max. values from another column where there is other data, and assign those a new definition in another column. I "think" I could do this in Access, but I'd rather try in Excel to avoid exports and imports...

Thanks very much and feel free to offer alternatives to Excel if necessary/appropriate!

Here is a table as an example:

[image]

Comment: Check this: https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-maxifs-function

Comment: Thank you! That would be great except that I don't have a recent enough version of Excel apparently... :( I'm looking to see if I can access a more current version through my University though!

Comment: Check this alternative: https://www.accountingweb.com/technology/excel/creating-excels-equivalent-of-maxif